# "Swapping" divs and data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, user-interface

Not sure the best way to word this, but I'm trying to replicate something similar to [Tinder](http://www.gotinder.com/). A video demonstration of the UI is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdechGTbQfY

Here's a Plunker of what I've got so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/zzb143PeO7QgnyKijFmG?p=preview

It works well enough (imagine the `.next` div sitting beneath the `.current` div, I just have them styled like this so I can see what's happening).

However, it's missing two things:

1. When the 'current' div is removed, it should slide away through ng-animate. Currently the data completely disappears and then reappears in new positions
2. (I suppose) the `.current` div needs to animate away first, then the `.next` div needs to become the `.current` div, then the next item in the `arr` array needs to be loaded into `.next`

I'm not very well-versed in Angular so not sure the best way to approach this, nor can I find any similar examples online. Any ideas on how to achieve a cards-like ui for Angular?

Comment: See examples here http://www.nganimate.org/ Just a matter of creating the css transitions you want

Comment: @charlietfl Those are just animations but don't really address the question

Comment: this will give you a good direction using animation on ng-repeat http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-ngrepeat

Comment: @Jascination you didn't look at the filtering repeater examples then. Seems to me is just what you want

Answer (score 0):

this post can help you 
http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-photo-slider-angularjs-animate/

here use http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/ but you can use another thing if you want